# Find a trigonometric equation describing a given solution set

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Write a trigonometric equation whose solution is the set given:
$\space 
\bigg\{| =\dfrac{\pi }{8}+\dfrac{\pi }{2}
\space  \lor \space 
 =\dfrac{−\pi }{8}+\dfrac{\pi }{2}, ∈ 
\bigg\}$

From what is provided in the equation, /2 is the period and it is possibly tangent. I am having trouble figuring out where to go next.

I have tried:

- graphing it on desmos to see if fiddling with it will magically show the equation.
- graphed it on a unit circle and I have found that it is possibly a tangent equation based on the +/- (/8). It is in the first and fourth quadrant, therefore its tangent.
- tried solving with the half-angle formula for tangent, but I get stuck figuring out where to input the what in the equation. I also don't know how to get cosine.

Comment: Please edit the question and especially the title, to make it a bit more clear what you're after. Perhaps 'Find a trigonometric equation describing a given solution set' or similar would be more fitting. Also, please include some of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have $$x=\pm\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{2k}$$
This can be rearranged as
$$\frac{\pi^2}{x\mp\frac{\pi}{8}}=2k\pi$$
So one possible trig equation could be $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{x\mp\frac{\pi}{8}}\right)=0$$

Comment: Having the $\pm$ in an equation like this is a bit strange.  A better choice might be $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{x- \pi/8}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{x + \pi/8}\right) = 0$$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes I guess that looks better. Mind you it's a pretty strange question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Given
$\space 
\bigg\{| =\dfrac{\pi }{8}+\dfrac{\pi }{2}
\space  \lor \space 
 =\dfrac{−\pi }{8}+\dfrac{\pi }{2}, ∈ 
\bigg\}$
the first part is
$$x=\dfrac{\pi }{2}\pm\dfrac{\pi }{8}
\quad=\dfrac{4\pm\pi k}{8}$$

I don't know how to derive a trig function here but we may reverse engineer "some" function with the quadratic formula.

$$x=\dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
=\dfrac{4\pm\pi k}{8}\\
\implies a=4k,\space b=-4$$

From here we see
$\space 
\sqrt{b^2-4ac} = \sqrt{16-4(4k)c}
=\sqrt{(\pi k)^2}\\
\implies 
c = \dfrac{16 - π^2 k^2}{16 k}
$

Therefore

$4kx^2-4x+\dfrac{16 - π^2 k^2}{16 k}\\
=64 k^2 x^2  - 64 k x - π^2 k^2 + 160\\
=(-8 k x - π k + 4) (-8 k x + π k + 4) =0$